# How to make this code more simple?

Tags: python

I have a small problem with this code

```
if    3 <= y <  7: self.draw_y -= 2
elif  7 <= y < 13: self.draw_y -= 3
elif 13 <= y < 17: self.draw_y -= 4
elif 17 <= y < 23: self.draw_y -= 5
elif 23 <= y < 27: self.draw_y -= 6
elif 27 <= y < 33: self.draw_y -= 7
elif 33 <= y < 37: self.draw_y -= 8
elif 37 <= y < 43: self.draw_y -= 9
elif 43 <= y < 47: self.draw_y -= 10
....
```

Could you help me to make this code simpler?

Comment: Is it guaranteed to alternate between +4 and +6?

Comment: Why don't you write a formula that takes `y` and calculates the value to subtract, instead?

Comment: Start from checking the largest values of y? Like `if 43 <= y < 47: self.draw_y -= 10` and then `elif y >= 37: self.draw_y -= 9` and so on..! You don't have to check less than condition this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not efficient, but cleaner:

```
if y >= 3:
    self.draw_y -= 2
    delta = 6
    while y >= 7:
        self.draw_y -= 1
        y -= delta
        delta = 6 if delta == 4 else 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def drawshift(x, l=[3,7,13,17,23,27,33,37,43,47]):
    return bisect_right(l, x) + 1

print(drawshift(2)) # 1
print(drawshift(3)) # 2
print(drawshift(4)) # 2
print(drawshift(7)) # 3
print(drawshift(43)) # 10
print(drawshift(47)) # 11
```

The documentation for the module I have used can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html). It uses a bisection algorithm (basically, binary search) which has O(log n) lookup time.

The edge cases like `x < 3` or `x >= 47` can be handled pretty simply with conditional statements. For example note that `bisect_right(x)` where x is lower than all elements of the list will return 0 and that `bisect_right(x)` where x is greater than or equal to the highest element in the list will give you `len(l) + 1`.

Comment: You should only import `bisect_right` once.  I suggest moving it out of the function.

Comment: This solution assumes the list of intervals is finite. The ellipsis in the OP's post seems to indicate otherwise. So e.g. `58` should be mapped to `13`. Yes, you could pass a new list, but it would also have a limited length.

Comment: @OliverW. True, but it is one way for large finite sequences and it works even if the boundaries are arbitrary with no pattern. If it was an infinite sequence, then one could also assume that OP would already have started with the math formula for it rather than starting with an if-elif statement chain, realizing that he/she would never finish it and then posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem, it uses simple arithmetic (division and modulo) and can be easily adapted for vectorization in case you're ever looking into that:

```
def range_selector(num):
    q, r = divmod(num - 3, 10)
    return 2*q + 2 + (r>=4)
```

Example, using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.array([3,6,7,13,14,47])
>>> range_selector(y)
array([ 2,  2,  3,  4,  4, 11])
```